# Number of elements in this range? Need help in this wierd question!

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, trigonometry

Okay, so once again. Same scenario. Going through JEE advanced questions. Came across this.

**Question**: S={$a^{b^C}$; a,b,c $\in${$tanx,cot$x}, for some given $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$}. If all the elements of S are written in ascending order, then the number of elements of S lie between $cot(x)^{cot(x)^{tan(x)}}$ and $tan(x)^{tan(x)^{tan(x)}}$ is /are:
**Options** (It's a single option correct MCQ):
A.1
B.3
C.4
D.5

I really Don't have the answer to this question but I tried to think it out this way.
in $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ , $cot(x)>1 $ and $tan(x)<1 $ but putting this on the two given end points, I am getting no decisive measure of the quantities. What should be the approach for solving this problem? Am i going right or I'm missing something under my nose?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

On the interval$\;(0,\pi/4),\;$we have$\;\;\cot(x) > 1\;\;\text{and}\;\;0 < \tan(x) < 1.$

Of the $8$ possible expressions, all the ones with $\cot$ on the bottom are more than $1$. All the ones with $\tan$ on the bottom are less than $1$. When a base is more than $1$, a bigger exponent makes it even bigger. When a base is strictly between $0$ and $1$, a bigger exponent makes it even smaller.

That's all you need to know.

Comment: So, going by this. The answer should be 3?

Comment: Yes, 3. Which ones?